# Regular locations versus named locations

Tags: nginx

I have a Rails app running with Thin, and I want Nginx to act as a reverse proxy to pass all the requests under a given location to the Thin server.

From all that I’ve read (and it’s been quite a lot) it seems that the most popular solution is to have the following site configuration file:

```
upstream thin {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    ...
    location /thin {
        proxy_pass http://thin;
    }
}
```

However, in my case, the problem with this setup is that the `/thin` part is passed to Thin. I’ve elsewhere read that for this reason it’s better to use a named location:

```
server {
    ...
    location @thin {
        proxy_pass http://thin;
    }
}
```

However, when I use this configuration, checking `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I see that the requests are not passed to the Thin server (the server is located at IP address 192.168.1.15 and the client is 192.168.1.105):

```
2013/04/11 12:55:58 [error] 17988#0: *1 open() "/var/www/thin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.105, server: , request: "GET /thin HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.15"
```

What am I doing wrong? How are named locations handled and what purpose do they serve?

Comment: I forgot to add that if named locations are a way to handle requests directed from other regular locations for complex rule sets (as the documentation seems to suggest), what can be accomplished with them that regular locations can’t? How are they successfully matched?

Answer (score 2):

Named locations are not used during normal processing of requests, they are intended only to process internally redirected requests (for example, with error_page, try_files).

Try to use

```
server {
    ...
    location /thin {
        proxy_pass http://thin/;
    }
}
```

Notice the slash at the end.

Comment: Yeah, it's similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/497102/relocating-application-in-nginx/497113#497113

Comment: Ok, I found out how to use named locations and their purpose. Thanks for the answer, though! Just one question, the solution you point out would replace the `/thin` part of the URI when passing the request to the Thin server? From what I’ve read from the link @poige provided (thanks, too), is it because of the trailing slash in `http://thin/;` ?

Comment: Yep! It's because of the trailing slash in proxy_pass.